# How to preview component with react portal using storybook.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, react-portal

I implemented a Popper component using popper.js, and I used React's Portal to render popper element.

And now I want to preview my popper component, but It fails to create portal on storybook.js

Here's my approach.

***.storybook/preview.js***

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';
import { Global } from '@emotion/react';
import { theme, normalize } from 'custom-theme';

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};

export const decorators = [
  Story => (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Global styles={normalize} />
        {Story()}
        <div id="popper-root"></div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  ),
];
```

***Portal.tsx***

```js
import { ReactNode, useMemo } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

interface IPortal {
  children: ReactNode;
  portalId: string;
}

const Portal = ({ children, portalId }: IPortal) => {
  const portalElement = useMemo<HTMLElement | null>(
    () => document.getElementById(portalId),
    [portalId],
  );

  if (!portalElement) {
    throw new Error(`Undefined Portal Id : ${portalId}`);
  }

  return createPortal(children, portalElement);
};

export default Portal;
```

***Capture of Error Message***

[image: Error Image]

Is there any way to show component using react portal on storybook? If not, is there other way to preview it other than testing it on react project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do a workaround on this by adding
`<div id="popper-root"></div>` to my ComponentStory Template.

But One thing is if I render story with portal open, it cannot find `popper-root`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `preview-body.html`, next to `preview.js`, with this:

```
<div id="popper-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked when added a div in `preview-body.html` as shown below. In order to reflect that in the storybook you need to restart the storybook.

```
<div id="popper-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a root element `id` in storybook to use for the portal. And I have used it for the React/Next.js portal. Now it's working well.

- Storybook root element  `<div id="docs-root"></div>`
- portal element selector  `document.getElementById('docs-root)`